# Where to get testnet Eth?

Tags: testnets, ropsten, rinkeby

Where do you get testnet Eth now that Ethereum has moved to POS?

All the faucets I used to use no longer work.

Comment: Ropsten and Rinkeby are both deprecated, i recommend to migrate to Goerli or Sepolia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a developer advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/). After the merge, many major Ethereum testnets like Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby, etc have been depreciated. Now, developers can choose between the goerli and sepolia testnet for testing their dapps.

Here's a [curated list of faucets](https://github.com/arddluma/awesome-list-testnet-faucets) that you can use.

We at Chainstack are also doing a [goerli eth giveaway](https://gleam.io/99AYj/chainstack-goerli-eth-giveaway). Feel free to check it out

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Goerli Ethereum testnet:
https://goerlifaucet.com/